# Please suggest me an application like Cambly to excel Russian speaking

Tags: online-learning, russian

I am hardly trying to find an application platform for conversation in Russian language with some tutors form Russia or eastern Slavic countries.

I need an application like [Cambly](https://www.cambly.com/english?lang=en) to exchange some words and check my Russian speaking skills. Does there any application or a free website exist?

Comment: Lingvist has training in Russian.  I found it to be quite good.  It has speaking practice exercises.